# Flask Sql Alchemy Relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I cannot make one-to-one relationship in Flask SQL Alchemy. Right after running the command `flask-init` in the terminal I get the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition
>   between parent/child tables on relationship TimeZones.users - there
>   are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing
>   columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or
>   specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.

I have three (3) tables.

1. Languages
2. TimeZones
3. User

**Table User have primary keys of Languages table and TimeZones table.**

Following is the code for all three table:

**1. Languages**

```
from modules.user_management.user_model import *

class Languages(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    language_culture = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    language_rtl = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    language_code = db.Column(db.String(50))
    is_published = db.Column(db.Integer)

    language_resources = db.relationship('LanguageResources', backref=db.backref('languages', lazy=True))
    users = db.relationship('User', backref=db.backref('languages', lazy=True))
```

**2. TimeZones**

```
from modules.user_management.user_model import *

class TimeZones(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    time_zone = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)

    users = db.relationship('User', backref=db.backref('timezones', lazy=True))
```

**3. User**

```
from modules.setups.language_model import *
from modules.setups.time_zone_model import *

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    language_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('languages.id'), nullable=False)
    timezone_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('timezones.id'), nullable=False)

    user_logs = db.relationship('UserLogs', backref=db.backref('user', lazy=True))
```

Following the tutorial available on the below link, I cannot find any problem.

http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/models/